# NullPointerException in android AsyncTask class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get data through web services, So that I'm using below shown asynctask calls. It gives me a null point exception as shown in the below screen shot. What can be the issue?

Activity class

```
new PickupAsyncTask(getApplicationContext(), null).execute();
```

Asynctask class

```
public class PickupAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray> {
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    private JSONArray responseJson = null;
    private Context contxt;
    private Activity activity;

    public PickupAsyncTask(Context context, OnTaskCompleted listener) {

        // API = apiURL;
        this.contxt = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // async task to accept string array from context array
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

        String path = null;
        String response = null;
        HashMap<String, String> request = null;
        JSONObject requestJson = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = null;
        StringEntity requestString = null;
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = null;

        try {
            path = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/LocationService.svc/StreetDetails";

            new URL(path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            // set the API request
            request = new HashMap<String, String>();
            request.entrySet().iterator();

            // Store locations in JSON
            requestJson = new JSONObject(request);
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(path);
            requestString = new StringEntity(requestJson.toString());

            // sets the post request as the resulting string
            httpPost.setEntity(requestString);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Handles the response
            responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

            responseJson = new JSONArray(response);
            System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + responseJson.length());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return responseJson;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        listener.onTaskCompleted(responseJson); //line 101
    }

}
```

OnTaskCompleted.java

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
    void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listener` is `null`. Introduce a check to verify that `listener` is not `null` before calling any methods on it.

**Edit**

If you want to handle the task completion, pass an anonymous object of `OnTaskCompleted` to `PickupAsyncTask` constructor as follows:

```
new PickupAsyncTask(context, new OnTaskCompleted() {

        @Override
        public void onTaskCompleted(JsonArray response) {
            //Handle the task completion

        }
    }).execute();
```

Comment: Inside my activity this is how I'm using calling the async task, new PickupAsyncTask(getApplicationContext(), null).execute(); I think this is the reason, how can I change it

Comment: Implement `OnTaskCompleted` interface and pass the reference to the object as the second parameter.

Comment: Check the updated answer. You may have to implement additional methods of the interface if there are more.